# Unity How to check if Object does not exist

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, unityscript

Ok,I have 2 coins in my scene both of them called "Coin" if the ship Triggered the coin the coin Destroy by calling

```
Destroy(this.gameObject);
```

I also have a lander which is NOT activated (by unchecking the check mark next to the object name in inspector)

So I have to coins when both coins are destroyed I want the lander to be active. I've done that and working by this code in the coin script :

```
var landing : GameObject;

function OnTriggerEnter2D (other : Collider2D) {

    Destroy(this.gameObject);
    if(Coin){

        Debug.Log("Object exist");

    }else{

        landing.SetActive(true);

    }

}
```

the result am having is the coin destroys when I hit the first coin (That what should happen) but when I hit the next coin it destroys but without making the lander active so how can I make the lander active only if no coin exist on the scene

Comment: Where is `Coin` assigned? I suspect it could be pointing at your prefab, which will always exist. What you need is something that looks at *the entire scene* for relevant GameObjects. So, perhaps `GameObject.Find("Coin")` - but this is expensive to perform, so you shouldn't use that frequently if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the question the best I could so it can work but keep being as simple as apparently you are trying to keep it. I have not tested it since I'm working right now. I think it should work from the top of my head if not mistaken.  Let me know.

Also if I were to do this for generic use I'll make a 'Coin Monitor gameObject' and will populate an Array or better yet, List of Coins and will just tell that manager to subtract coins until the final condition is met.  Then it will work right for N coins.

Another way could be to tag the Coins and then do a gameobject find at the start() of your gameObject but if it were me I would still prefer the manager solution and is much more powerful and flexible, as you can extend it to make a bunch of additional stuff related to the coins on your game.

---

This is because you are Destroying() the coin _before activating the landing.SetActive(), just move Destroy() the line to the end, after the if (Coin) ends, it should fix it.

```js
// Coin gameObject script - This sample code requires that you Tag your Ship gameObject: "Ship"

// Note this is not too efficient as you have to assign trough the Inspector!
public var landing : GameObject;
public var myOtherCoin : GameObject;

function OnTriggerEnter2D (other : Collider2D) {

    if ( other.tag == "Ship" )
    {
      if ( myOtherCoin != null )
      {
        Debug.Log( "There's still another coin, Self destructing..." );
        Destroy( this.gameObject );
      }
      else
      {
        Debug.Log( "There's no other coins.. Activating Landing!" );
        landing.SetActive( true );
        Debug.Log( "Landing Active... Self destructing now!" );
        Destroy( this.gameObject );
      }
    } 
  
}
```

Comment: Still the lander never become true

Comment: I have 2 Coins sharing the same script and the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd create another GameObject in the scene, an arbiter of sorts, which would have a script containing the number of existing coins (2 at the beginning) and a method to decrement this counter.
Then, before destroying your coin, you will call this method in the arbiter. Furthermore, in the decrement method, you could check the number of coins, and if you have just decremented it to 0, automatically activate the landing pad. It's definitely cheaper then to periodically check the whole scene for coins.